# What are some interesting herbs/spices to sprinkle over fish?

Tags: spices, fish, herbs

I typically just pan fry my fish (typically cod, rockfish or salmon).  For cod I dip it in batter (egg+flour) and for salmon, I marinate it in a Tandoori-ish type of yogurt-based marinade.  In all cases I use an impromptu made mix of spices consisting typically of ginger powder, coriander, turmeric, and cayenne pepper.

I often feel that some specific fish spice/herb would fit in better. Anybody have any suggestion?  I don't like processed spices (like Old Bay), I prefer base ingredients (don't even use premixed curry).

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/The-Flavor-Bible-Creativity-Imaginative/dp/0316118400/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1395049492&sr=8-1&keywords=flavor+bible

Answer (score 2):

One of the best seasonings that works as a base for fish is "zesty lemon and pepper seasoning salt" by McCormik which is currently available in Costco stores. You can make that from scratch, however it is difficult to find the dehydrated lemon.

To take your seasoning to the next gourmet level, mix in powdered saffron and dried parsley. Also, if you can find "Aleppo peppers" the spice  in your area, use that too.

I mix the following ingredients to make my fish seasoning:

1 tbsp lemon and pepper seasoning salt (recommended, McCormik)

1 tbsp Aleppo peppers

1 tbsp dried parsley

1 tsp powdered saffron

1 tsp onion powder

1 tsp freshly ground black peppers

1 tsp or so kosher salt

Place all the ingredients in a stone mortar or spice grinder and coarsely powder them ,not very fine though, just enough to soften the parsley and blend every thing together.